# How to rename some values ​in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, windows

I'm doing a project in pandas and I have a question that I can't solve

```
import pandas

archive = pandas.read_excel('arc.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')

archive.head(20)
```

returned this to me

```
    Color   Minute

0   Pink    23:59
1   Green   23:59
2   Pink    23:58
3   Blue    23:58
4   Green   23:57
5   Pink    23:57
6   Blue    23:56
7   Pink    23:56
8   Blue    23:55
9   Blue    23:55
10  Pink    23:54
11  Green   23:54
12  Pink    23:53
13  Blue    23:53
14  Green   23:52
15  Blue    23:52
16  Green   23:51
17  Pink    23:51
18  Blue    23:50
19  Pink    23:50
```

But this file has more than 2 thousand lines, I wanted the code to read the entire 'color' column and if each column value was 'Blue' it would rename the value to '0', if it was pink, it would rename it to '1' ' and finally if it was 'Green' it would be renamed to '2'

It seems like a very simple thing, but I couldn't find it!

I tried the rename method and a few more things and it just returned an error!

Comment: You can try `df['Color'].map({'Blue':0,'Pink':1,'Green':2})` (assuming your dataframe is called df). Have a look a [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html)

Comment: this code really helped me thanks